# Unable to use matplotlib after installation "no module named 'matplotlib'"

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, installation, package

I am brand new to Python and am following the tutorial at this link:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial

I was able to execute

```
python -m pip install matplotlib
```

However, then when trying to run script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x))
plt.show()
```

I get:

```
PS C:\Code\Astros\Prism> & C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe c:/Code/Astros/Prism/Prism.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Code/Astros/Prism/Prism.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
PS C:\Code\Astros\Prism>
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check where the `matplotlib` package has been installed through this command?

```
pip show matplotlib
```

And you are using the global Python on your computer:

```
C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe
```

It should be different.

You can switch to the python interpreter which you have installed the packages you want to import. Or install the packages in the interpreter you are using.

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal in same directory:
make venv by typing :
**python -m venv venv.**

then activate it
**venv/scripts/activate**
then install matplotlib by pip.
this should work

Comment: Thanks Yussef, I had tried that already and it had not worked.